# DD4T Migrated to GitHub

Tags: discussion

As you may know, DD4T has recently been migrated from [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/) to [GitHub](https://github.com/dd4t/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion) in an effort to make it easier to contribute. Making use of GitHub's nicer toolset and also to streamline the release process. The plan is to use [a Forking Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-forking).

That means you can now fork DD4T and create pull requests to get your code back in easily. Hopefully we can get a CI server set up soon.

There's plenty of jobs to do if anyone wants to volunteer to help out! Join [the Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion) and get involved!

Any questions or discussion add below.

A [recording of the board meeting](https://ws.cubbyusercontent.com/p/_80896b063f254e1da1595a0f07b08101/Instant+Meeting+2014-09-02.webm/988198835) where we discuss the move is available.

Comment: Good stuff! I will fork shortly to create a pull request to get my pimped up image resizing in the .NET BinaryFileManager